# How to watch slice of C++ array in VS while debugging?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, fortran

I want to debug multi dimensional C++ array in Visual Studio.

In Intel Fortran( integrated in VS), assume arr is a 2 dimension array, and I can use "arr(2:5,3:8)" to see the slice of the array.

[image]

Intel Fortran can do this in VS2010. How can I achieve the same goal if I write an own defined class (like CMultiDimensionArray) in C++?

Comment: If you switch to std::vector, VS will show it neatly

Answer (score 2):

You can create a custom native visualizer (.natvis) for your class to render the object however you like. See [Creating Custom Views of Native Objects](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj620914.aspx). There is even an example of a custom view for multidimensional arrays on that linked page.

Comment: But natvis seems cannot accept parameter. That is I can use natvis to custom display "ii", but i can't display "ii(2:3,4:5)".

I am not familiar with natvis, is it right？

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no way to pass parameters to a natvis representation.  I've been advocating for this for a while, but there is nobody listening or it's too complex for them to bother.  You can, however, create static ones and modify that while debugging, or maybe you could create psudo type copies based on the original type that uses ExcludeView/IncludeView and the view() modifier for having multiple views of the same type.

Example type:

```
struct myarray
{
  int x[10][10];
};
```

Example default view:

```
<Type Name="myarray" IncludeView="x">
  <Expand>
    <CustomListItems>
      <!-- Parameters -->
      <Variable Name="x_begin" InitialValue="2"/>
      <Variable Name="x_end"   InitialValue="5"/>
      <Variable Name="y_begin" InitialValue="3"/>
      <Variable Name="y_end"   InitialValue="8"/>

      <!-- Local variables -->
      <Variable Name="x_index" InitialValue="x_begin"/>
      <Variable Name="y_index" InitialValue="y_begin"/>
      <Loop Condition="y_index &lt;= y_end">
        <Exec>x_index=x_begin</Exec>
        <Loop Condition="x_index &lt;= x_end">
          <Item Name="[{x_index}, {y_index}]">x[x_index][y_index]</Item>
          <Exec>++x_index</Exec>
        </Loop>
        <Exec>++y_index</Exec>
      </Loop>
    </CustomListItems>
  </Expand>
</Type>

<Type Name="myarray">
  <Expand>
    <CustomListItems>
      <!-- Parameters -->
      <Variable Name="x_begin" InitialValue="0"/>
      <Variable Name="x_end"   InitialValue="10"/>
      <Variable Name="y_begin" InitialValue="0"/>
      <Variable Name="y_end"   InitialValue="10"/>

      <!-- Local variables -->
      <Variable Name="x_index" InitialValue="x_begin"/>
      <Variable Name="y_index" InitialValue="y_begin"/>
      <Loop Condition="y_index &lt;= y_end">
        <Exec>x_index=x_begin</Exec>
        <Loop Condition="x_index &lt;= x_end">
          <Item Name="[{x_index}, {y_index}]">x[x_index][y_index]</Item>
          <Exec>++x_index</Exec>
        </Loop>
        <Exec>++y_index</Exec>
      </Loop>
    </CustomListItems>
  </Expand>
</Type>
```

Example useage in watch window (assume a variable named `array` of type x exists):

1. Show default:

   array
2. Show custom:

   array, view(x)

Note that the view names are case sensitive but do not like any non alphanumeric characters.  As soon as it sees one, it considers that the end of the name in the natvis file and will not match if you use the view name.

I.e. name is "hello there", view(hello) will match, but view(hello there) will not.  Thus don't use underscores or punctuation in your names.